# Using -Objc Flag in XCode Gives Mach-O Linker Errors

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I am trying to integrate google AdMobs into my iOS app, but in order to use their SDK I need to use the -ObjC linker flag to load their category methods. Everything works perfectly without the linker, but when I add the -ObjC flag in Xcode under Debug and Release I get a huge list of Mach-O linker errors (below).

I'm using Box2D, which uses both C and C++, so at first I thought I just needed to include the appropriate linker flag, but I couldn't find one that fixed the errors.

I also tried importing the libstdc++.dylib library, which got rid of the original linker errors and instead replaced them with errors claiming I had a ton of duplicate symbols in my CCScrollLayer.

I'm at a loss. Any help at all would be very, very much appreciated.

-Objc Errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      ...
  "std::allocator<char>::allocator()", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::allocator<char>::~allocator()", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::istream::operator>>(float&)", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::istream::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::istream::operator>>(unsigned int&)", referenced from:
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::istream::operator>>(unsigned long&)", referenced from:
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::istream::operator>>(long long&)", referenced from:
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(float)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<float>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::ostream::operator<<(long long)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_istringstream(std::string const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()", referenced from:
      float stringToValue<float>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      int stringToValue<int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned int stringToValue<unsigned int>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      unsigned long stringToValue<unsigned long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      long long stringToValue<long long>(char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      ...
  "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()", referenced from:
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<int>(char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<float>(char const*, float) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<long long>(char const*, long long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned long>(char const*, unsigned long) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      TiXmlElement* createValueElm<unsigned int>(char const*, unsigned int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      void setAttribute<int>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, int) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      ...
  "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<long long const, cpShape*> >::operator--() in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<long long const, cpBody*> >::operator--() in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<long long const, cpShape*> >::operator++() in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<long long const, cpBody*> >::operator++() in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<long long, std::pair<long long const, cpShape*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long long const, cpShape*> >, std::less<long long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long long const, cpShape*> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<long long const, cpShape*> const&) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<long long, std::pair<long long const, cpBody*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<long long const, cpBody*> >, std::less<long long>, std::allocator<std::pair<long long const, cpBody*> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<long long const, cpBody*> const&) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      void setAttribute<char const*>(TiXmlElement*, char const*, char const*) in libchipmunk-spacemanager-ios.a(cpSpaceSerializer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Errors with the libstdc++.dylib:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.layers_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.currentScreen_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.pagesIndicatorNormalColor_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.pagesIndicatorSelectedColor_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.prevScreen_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.scrollTouch_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.startSwipe_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.state_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.marginOffset_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.delegate_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.minimumTouchLengthToSlide_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.minimumTouchLengthToChangePage_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.showPagesIndicator_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.pagesIndicatorPosition_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.pagesWidthOffset_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CCScrollLayer.stealTouches_ in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScrollLayer in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CCScrollLayer in:
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Intermediates/ballBounce.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ballBounce-iOS.build/Objects-normal/i386/CCScrollLayer.o
    /Users/Stevenpd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Kobold2D-bhlexwnjvtnneigernvsargfadgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcocos2d-extensions-ios.a(CCScrollLayer.o)
ld: 18 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Linker errors means either some framework is missing or some lib is missing when you try to run, when build your app you won't be getting any error, i have also implemented the Admobs sdk, the error is not because of the -Objc linker flag.

Comment: I don't know who is doing all the downvoting of legitimate, well written questions at the moment, but perhaps they'd like to explain *why* they are downvoting.

Comment: exactly, people just down vote and don't write why they did that, SO should make compulsory to write a comment why  you down voted the Que/Ans.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You might be right about the libraries. All my AdMobs libraries are added, but I'm using Kobold2D and it appears that the libraries it references (including Box2D) are in red on my list of libraries. I'm not sure how to properly add them, though. I thought they were already taken care of because it works fine without the -ObjC flag

Comment: I don't see how adding `libstd++.dylib` (something you shouldn't need to do explicitly) caused those duplicate symbols as those errors should always be there (i.e. the inclusion of the C++ runtime library didn't cause them).

Comment: I'm not sure either. Also, my Kobold2D workspaces' libraries appear to be fine. I think Kobold2D references the default libraries in the build path rather than including the hard code in the heart of the app. Would the -ObjC linker create a problem because of that by chance?

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem – the solution was to simply use –force_load, which targeted the google library specifically