# Is adMob's -ObjC linker flag necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, linker-errors, linker-flags

The reason I'm asking is it builds fine without the flag.
But if I do add the flag, it throws a bunch of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

from Parse SDK apparently.

However since its stated in [their guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios), I wonder if its alright to omit it.

I did see others having this issue, and [some saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774984/using-objc-flag-in-xcode-gives-mach-o-linker-errors) `-force_load` will fix it, but I'm not sure what exactly `-ObjC` and `-force_load` does, so I have no idea how to use it.

Doubt I'm missing any frameworks too since it builds fine without the flag?

**Update**:

I found out how to use `-force_load` [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/admob-build-error). But would still appreciate if someone can help explain what's going on with the `-ObjC` and `-force_load` flags.

The linker flag to use should be `-force_load libGoogleAdMobAds.a` instead of `-ObjC`.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Labraries is all required frameworks added

Answer (score 0):

You need to to link also:

```
Social.framework
Accounts.framework
```

go to the projects **Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries** and add them. If you already have them try to remove them and add them back.

I have this issue and i added these and it was fixed.

Found it here [Parse Starter Project LogIn and Register View Controllers Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253410/parse-starter-project-login-and-register-view-controllers-errors)